# Can I add an alphabet jump list to a tableview like the contact list

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I would like to create a custom contact list in my app offering a similar A-Z jump list like the standard contact list does.

Is this possible with a TableView?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a comprehensive tutorial on how to do it in the ["Table View Programming Guide"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html), called "Populating an Indexed List".

Moreover, if you also need to have the search functionality (the magnify icon), there are two well written solutions:

- http://iamthewalr.us/blog/2009/12/uisearchdisplaycontroller-and-uilocalizedindexedcollation/
- http://lukeredpath.co.uk/blog/using-uilocalizedindexedcollation-with-searchable-table-views.html

Comment: “Sorry, that page cannot be found”. That much for permanent URLs, Apple!

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 4.0 and 5.0**
Just implement the following methods and return the list.

```
 var list = ["A","B","C","D"];

 override func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    return list
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely, just return an array of `NSStrings` from the `UITableViewDataSource` method `-sectionIndexTitlesForTableView`

For the record, this "jump list" is called a **section index**.

You also need to correspond this with the actual amount of sections that you have, if not, then you can use `tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:` to play around with which sections get shown for which indexes.

The [docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:), my friend, read the docs.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [UITableViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:) documentation. There's a method `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:` and `tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:`. These should get you going.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Implement the [`-sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:` method](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006941-CH3-SW5) in the data source.

See the [TableViewSuite](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) example code for how to use it.