# Sorting Array Alphabetically for section tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

How to sort an array alphabetically to return all objects data instead of single name? And how to set these data in section tableview? Number of rows in section method - how it works, please help me.

Comment: what does the array contain?

Comment: Array contain list of contacts name,email and phone no from adress book. o want to sort alphabatically object wise not just single name i mean i want to sort array in which array have name ,phone and email then this array i will pas to section table

Comment: so your array contains contact objects, right? could just paste the class definition for your contact's object?

Comment: yes I have array of contact i want responce in this formate letter=A {list;(name=@"Anisar"; Phone=@"03484863" ; email=@"janisr.com")}; simailarly letter=B{list;list;(name=@"Bnisar"; Phone=@"03484863" ; email=@"banisr.com")};} etc plz help me

Comment: letter A have name begin with A included their phone no and email and letter B have names begin with B etc please help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I add an alphabet jump list to a tableview like the contact list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773340/can-i-add-an-alphabet-jump-list-to-a-tableview-like-the-contact-list)

Comment: what's your problem? you wanted to sort the values of your NSArray?

Comment: Dear vignesh I have array of contact i want responce in this formate letter=A {list;(name=@"Anisar"; Phone=@"03484863" ; email=@"janisr.com")}; simailarly letter=B{list;list;(name=@"Bnisar"; Phone=@"03484863" ; email=@"banisr.com")};} etc plz help me

Comment: Dear Burhanuddin Sunelwala i want exectly this solution http://iamthewalr.us/blog/2009/12/uisearchdisplaycontroller-and-uilocalizedindexedcollation/ but here source code for section and array not present just seach code here plz send me source

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your array with a sort descriptor. in the sort descriptor you set the attrib of the array elements which shall be used for sorting:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"yourAttribInArrayElememts" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedArray = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
```

Comment: Dear Throb65 I have array of contact i want responce in this formate letter=A {list;(name=@"Anisar"; Phone=@"03484863" ; email=@"janisr.com")}; simailarly letter=B{list;list;(name=@"Bnisar"; Phone=@"03484863" ; email=@"banisr.com")};} etc plz help me

Answer (score 0):

Create this method inside your Object class

```
-(NSComparisonResult) compareWithObjectClass: (YourObjectClass *) otherObject
{
  return [self.name compare:otherObject.name]
}
```

Then, in your viewcontroller, you can call sortUsingComparator method to order your array of objects

```
 //Order items Array
[self.itemsArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(YourObjectClass *obj1, YourObjectClass *obj2){
           return [obj1compareWithObjectClass:obj2];
      }];
```